# Is there a way to disable showing what your friends are playing when first logging into steam?

Tags: steam

Whenever I log onto steam and open it on the top right of my computer is shows everyone who is playing games but at 3 at a time. Due to my high number or friends it takes a good amount of time to cycle through them. That means any icons or images in my top right of the screen are blocked and I can't click on them until the list goes away. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The only way to disable this is to disable friend notifications entirely.

In Steam's settings, go to the Friends tab and uncheck "When any Friend joins a game" "Display a notification".

[image: Steam Fiend Notifications]

Edit: As @ardaozkal has pointed out, you can override this per friend by opening the friends list, clicking the down arrow next to their name and clicking 
Notification Options.  Then, under "When [person name] joins a game" check the "Display a notification" box.

Comment: This. So much this. I recommend doing this and then enabling this for the friends you actually care about what they are playing.

Comment: FYI this is now under Friends | View Friends List. 
 You need to (unfortunately) sign in to "Friends and Chat", then a Gear button appears where you can edit the notification setting.

Answer (score 45):

There's not a "only after login" option for displaying these friend notifications.  As has been noted, it's all or nothing in Steam's settings.  There's also no launch option that helps.

However, you can make it go faster, if you edit your Steam style.  In your Steam directory, look for `resource\styles\steam.style`.  (Assuming you use the default skin - if not, check the `\skins\(skin name)\resource\styles` directory)  Back up this file, and then you can edit it.  Search for "Notifications." and you should see a block like:

```
Notifications.PanelPosition     "BottomRight"   // Can be "BottomRight", "BottomLeft", "TopRight", "TopLeft"
Notifications.PanelPosition     "TopRight" [$OSX]  // the dock is on the bottom for OSX, so instead pop top right like other apps do
Notifications.SlideDirection    "Vertical"    // Can be "Vertical", "Horizontal", "None" and controls slide effect
Notifications.FadeInTime      "0.45"    // Controls the time it takes to slide/fade into view
Notifications.FadeOutTime     "0.45"    // Controls the time it takes to slide/fade out of view
Notifications.DisplayTime     "6.0"     // Controls the length of time at steady state after fade in and before fade out
Notifications.StackSize       "3"     // Controls how many panels we will stack before background queuing
```

You can move the notifications to some other corner, have more on the screen at once, and make them cycle faster if you so desire.